# Homotopy between R and I

Tags: general-topology

Consider $f(t)=(\cos(\pi t),\sin(\pi t))$ and $g(t)=(\cos(\pi t),-\sin(\pi t))$. Then either:

(a) Prove that $f,g \colon I \to \mathbb{R}^2$ are homotopic.

Comment: What have your tried?

Comment: So, what's your question?

Comment: You'll find that posts which simply present a problem for us to solve and you to copy will easily attract down votes and close votes. Keep in mind: this is a question and answer site. Do you have a question? For example, did you try something that didn't work and you have a question about that?

Comment: See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) for tips on how to write a good question, and more specifically see [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960) for providing some context such as including your own work, and [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933) for avoiding "I have no clue" questions.

Answer (score 1):

The winding numbers with respect to zero are 1 and -1 respectively.  The curves cannot be homotopic in the plane punctured at the origin.